# Gupnp-av control point does not work with Hupnp media server

Tags: upnp, gupnp

This is a somewhat general question I fear, I am seeking advice from those familiar with upnp-av protocol. See, I cloned and built Hupnp library [both the original version in qt4, and a ported version in qt5] to use its media server. I also cloned and built gupnp-tools to use their av-control point. Now here is the situation :

gupnp-av cp works well in general.
Hupnp library works well with some control points but doesn't work well with others.
gupnp-av cp doesnot work with Hupnp. It manages to see the server, but doesn't list the contents.

After some investigation, I see that: For the applications that do work well with Hupnp, they send two upnp browse action requests ,  one for "BrowseMetaData" , followed by "BrowseAllChildren" after Hupnp sends the response. As for Gupnp-av , it only sends "BrowseMetaData" without the other browse request. I checked that the response to "BrowseMetaData" from Hupnp to Gupnp arrives successfully.

I am just seeking really general advice as I am no expert on the subject. My goal is to make Hupnp work well with gupnp (and other control points that suffer the same problems) [as part of opensource contribution]. Why does this behaviour occur ? Why for some control points only and some others work perfectly ? and Where should I look to improve the situation? 
any advice is highly appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: There are many possible reasons why interoperation fails -- UPnP AV is very complex. gupnp-av-cp itself is just 2500 lines of open source C code (look for gupnp-tools repository): you should be able to find out the reason it doesn't work by either reading the code (and at the same time looking at the data going on the wire) or by debugging gupnp-av-cp. I would first check whether there are any warnings when running from terminal though.

Comment: @jku   I already cloned the c code and running it  (inside qt creator). No warnings unfortunately. It just never calls the "BrowseAllChildren" when it comes to Hupnp, while it does call it with other upnp devices/servers. This is the response I get from Hupnp as a response to "BrowseMetaData "
https://justpaste.it/18cwb

Answer (score 1):

Jens Georg answered my question as I posted it to the gupnp mailing list. gupnp-av cp turned out to have a bug : If the server does not have an icon image, the second browse request doesn't get sent. so I only added an icon to the Hupnp-av server and all worked perfectly. weird.